# Unable to read events from systemd journal gateway

Tags: systemd, coreos, journald

I'm trying to forward systemd logs to the remote host and can't get `systemd-journal-gateway` working. I can connect to `http://localhost:19531/entries?follow` but there aren't any entries. In the same time `journalctl -f` shows new journal entries.

I have read docs for [systemd-journal-gatewayd.service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-gatewayd.service.html), but there are no glue about this case.

**EDIT:**

```
$ systemctl status systemd-journal-gatewayd
systemd-journal-gatewayd.service - Journal Gateway Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib64/systemd/system/systemd-journal-gatewayd.service; indirect; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-07-07 07:35:48 UTC; 2h 23min ago
 Main PID: 5183 (systemd-journal)
   Memory: 1.0M
      CPU: 236ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
           └─5183 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-gatewayd

Jul 07 07:35:48 ip-10-4-1-91.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started Journal Gateway Service.
Jul 07 07:35:48 ip-10-4-1-91.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting Journal Gateway Service...
```

**EDIT 2:**
`lsof` shows that system log accessed and open:

```
$ lsof -p 805
COMMAND   PID                    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
...
systemd-j 805 systemd-journal-gateway   11u  IPv6              17965      0t0    TCP localhost:http-alt->localhost:55344 (ESTABLISHED)
systemd-j 805 systemd-journal-gateway   12u   REG               0,32        0  18492 /tmp/#18492 (deleted)
systemd-j 805 systemd-journal-gateway   13r  0000               0,10        0   6679 anon_inode
systemd-j 805 systemd-journal-gateway   14r   REG              202,9  8388608     30 /var/log/journal/fdb957828b9941b29ef97394f06a0cdc/system.journal
```

But for some reason it don't shows them neither in web UI nor in direct http request.

Also, sometime in the web console for `http://x.x.x.x:19531/entries` I see `400 Bad request` `Failed to seek in journal`. But can't reproduce it with curl.

Comment: Please post the output of `systemctl status systemd-journal-gatewayd` in your question.

Comment: @Sekenre added output

Comment: Thanks, can you see anything when you go to: http://localhost:19531/browse

Comment: @Sekenre, I can see UI but no events there. Just UI.

Comment: Weird, sorry I don't know what else you could check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created [ticket](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/506) on the [systemd issue tracker](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues). And right now this issue [confirmed by systemd developers](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/506#issuecomment-119310015). Issue introduced some when after 219 release.